# Is it possible to declare a Map type that requires all enum values to be present as keys?

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

How can I require the Dart compiler to warn me when I forget to include all members of an enum in a map? For example, in the following:

```dart
enum Size {
  small,
  medium,
  large,
}

// This is a valid Dart code. Dart compiler doesn't require `Size.large` to be present.
final Map<Size, ButtonSize> sizeMap = {
  Size.small: const MyClass(),
  Size.medium: const MyClass(),
};
```

The Dart compiler isn't that restrictive. It doesn't require all enum values to be present in the `Map`, so I can't be sure that the following code will return an instance of `MyClass`. It might resolve to `null`:

```dart
final MyClass instance = sizeMap[Size.small]; // unsafe
```

I have to either do this:

```dart
final MyClass? instance = sizeMap[Size.small]; // `instance` might be `null`
```

or this:

```dart
final MyClass instance = sizeMap[Size.small] as MyClass; // `instance` might still be `null`, but we're pretending it's not.
```

Both solutions are far from perfect. The first one implies further `null` checks in the code, the second one smells because of typecasting.

Is there any way to declare the type of `sizeMap` so that all enum values must be present?

Comment: I'd assume that dart maps behave how maps would in JavaScript/TypeScript? `Map<Size, MyClass>` doesn't require you to define all members of the enum either.

Comment: Nope, In TS the object MUST contain ell enum keys. If you want some to be optional you need to use a `Partial` type, e.g. `type SizeMap = Partial<Record<Size, MyClass>>`;

Comment: I am referring to the `Map<K, V>` type that represents the native `Map` class in JavaScript. Maps don't care if you provided all members as long as it's a homogeneous map of things of type `K` to things of type `V`.

Comment: Oh, I get you, but it's irrelevant as I'm trying to illustrate the problem using TypeScript. The purpose of this post is not to point out the differences between the languages but the get a problem solved. In TS this problem is solved by using the `Record` type. I'm looking for an equivalent in Dart.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is just simply a class with required parameters?

Comment: No, because I want another class to just take one parameter: a `Size` enum, and based on that parameter pick the `MyClass` implementation from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Map`, you'd be better off with a function and a `switch` statement:

```dart
enum Size {
  small,
  medium,
  large,
}

class MyClass {
  const MyClass();
}

MyClass mapSize(Size size) {
  switch (size) {
    case Size.small:
      return const MyClass();
    case Size.medium:
      return const MyClass();
  }
}
```

the above code generates a **compile-time error** from not handling all `enum` values:

> Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'MyClass' doesn't allow null.

With null-safety, the above code *cannot* be executed until the above problem is fixed.

Additionally, `dart analyze` will produce a more descriptive warning:

> Missing case clause for 'large'. Try adding a case clause for the missing constant, or adding a default clause. • missing_enum_constant_in_switch

If you want to use a `Map` because you want to allow it to be mutated, you could provide separate functions to set and get values:

```dart
var _smallValue = const MyClass();
var _mediumValue = const MyClass();
var _largeValue = const MyClass();

MyClass mapSize(Size size) {
  switch (size) {
    case Size.small:
      return _smallValue;
    case Size.medium:
      return _mediumValue;
    case Size.large:
      return _largeValue;
  }
}

void setMappedSize(Size size, MyClass value) {
  switch (size) {
    case Size.small:
      _smallValue = value;
      break;
    case Size.medium:
      _mediumValue = value;
      break;
    case Size.large:
      _largeValue = value;
      break;
  }
}
```

If you find that to be too verbose, and you just want callers to avoid returning `null`, you could wrap a `Map` internally:

```dart
const _defaultValue = const MyClass();
final _sizeMap = <Size, MyClass>{};

MyClass mapSize(Size size) => _sizeMap[size] ?? _defaultValue;

void setMappedSize(Size size, MyClass value) => _sizeMap[size] = value;
```

Comment: Using `switch` is not a solution - it's a workaround. If an enum contains just a few items then it's OK (not perfect but acceptable), but if an enum is big enough then writing such code would be terribly tedious. Also, using `switch` implies that there will be always a default value, which I don't want. Imagine I have a class that takes the `Size` enum as a parameter. Then, with an enum and a map I can simply do: ` Size get _size => sizeMap[size];` and that's it (that's what I would do e.g. in TypeScript).

Comment: @wube Using a `switch` does not imply a default value.  Adding a `default` case will prevent compile-time warnings about unhandled `enum` values.

Comment: That's what I meant. If I want switch-based code to be null-safe I need to provide a default value which I want to avoid. I can do the same when using an enum/map. The thing is I would love to be able to define the type in such a way that the Dart compiler understands that the map contains all values. in TS, for instance, I can do: `type SizeMap =Record<Size, MyClass>`, which is not the case in Dart as the compiler doesn't require all enum values to be present in the map. Dart interprets it the same way as TypeScript compiler would interpret `type SizeMap = Partial<Record<Size, MyClass>>`.

Comment: @wube I don't understand what you're talking about.  You *must* not add a `default` case to `switch` if you want compile-time checks.  It does not prevent null-safety; in fact, the compile-time checks were added *for* null-safety.

Comment: Also, although `switch` might be more verbose than you prefer, it *is* the solution.  You need to accept that Dart `Map`s cannot do what you want.

Comment: I'm OK with accepting that fact, but so far it wasn't clear that Dart typing isn't capable to do it, I was just presented with an alternative solution. I don't agree that a switch is a solution because I can achieve exactly the same with maps if I wrap a map in a function/class that returns a default value.

Comment: @wube But you don't need a default value with a `switch`.  Using a `switch` statement allows you to have *all* of the following properties: 1. No default value. 2. A non-nullable return type. 3. A compile-time check that all `enum` values are handled.  Is that not what you're asking for?

Comment: Of course, that `switch` doesn't imply the default value. But if no default value is provided then the value returned by the `switch` clause might be `null` - that's the same problem the map-based solution suffers from. This is why I'm saying that `switch` doesn't solve the original problem. What I'm trying to achieve is null-safety without a default value. In TS I can achieve it by declaring a type: `type SizeMap =Record<Size, MyClass>`. I'm looking for a similar solution in Dart. I'm afraid that in Dart it's simply impossible.

Comment: @wube No.  As I keep trying to explain, such a `switch` statement could not return `null` with sound null-safety.  It would be impossible because failing to handle all `enum` cases would be a compile-time error.  It seems evident that you keep *thinking* a `switch` statement won't work without having properly tried it.  If you have an actual example where it doesn't do what you want, please provide that instead of reiterating the same TypeScript example.

Comment: @wube I've updated my answer to show you the compile-time error.